# Convert IP Address format from ForeFront Firewall logs with SQL

Tags: logging, ip, sql, microsoft-forefront

I am trying to query IP addresses from Forefront Firewall logs,  and I am a little stuck on the IP formatting

```
C0A8E008-FFFF-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Can anyone give me the MSSQL command to turn this into standard human redable?

UPDATE,  I now see that I kust need to convert the first 8 charecters from hex to decimal....which I can then convert to IP.  the trick is to parse those first charecters from the field with SQL

Comment: Can you paste the entire log line? Forefront documentation seems to point to it logging the IP address in standard dotted-decimal notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substring function to get the four octets of IP address. You can do:

```
SELECT hex_to_dec(substring(field, 1, 2)) + '.' + hex_to_dec(substring(field, 3, 2))
 + '.' + hex_to_dec(substring(field, 5, 2)) + '.' + hex_to_dec(substring(field, 7, 2))
 <FROM, WHERE ...>
```

I am not sure whether MSSQL has a function that does hex to decimal conversion `hex_to_sec`. You just need to find a proper way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in MSSQL but to give you an idea of the method, in your example above C0A8E008 is 192.168.224.08. Split C0A8E008 into four 2 hexdigit blocks and convert each into decimal.